# How to get meteor packages inside head in v 1.3

Tags: meteor

In meteor 1.3 package scripts are added inside body. So I'm not able to get exported variables from packages in the head tag.

client/main.html

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
  <script>
    console.log(ReactiveVar);
  </script>
</head>
```

client/main.js

```
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
console.log(ReactiveVar);
import './main.html';
```

But I can log the same variable from js files. This is because meteor is loading scripts inside body instead of head. Is there a possible workaround in this situation.?

When I add `import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';` to head script Browser Console shows the following error.

[image: Browser Console Error]

Here is a repo of a sample app https://github.com/aruntk/meteor-script-in-head.

Comment: Have you tried using `require`?

Comment: @corvid  Yes. Results in `unexpected token require.` error.

Comment: I'm getting `(index):7 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactiveVar is not defined`

Comment: And I don't think you should use any `script` tag in meteor

Comment: chances are that `ReativeVar` is loaded AFTER you use that script tag

Comment: Ya. Packages are loaded in body. But what if I want to use it this way. ?